# Teradata column usage details

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I have been a lurking visitor here for years, but I think this is my first time asking a question, so here goes:

Is there a way in Teradata SQL Assistant 16.20 to find how often specific table columns are used in queries, without being a DB admin? Basically, we have a rather large table that keeps growing in number of columns, and we would like to deprecate ones that are not being used by anyone but can't very well ask over 100 users which columns they use. My team "manages" this table to the extent of creating it and populating the data, but we do not have full admin rights to the database, so any solution that would require full DB access isn't really an option without submitting a ticket, which I can do but would rather find a solution I can do on my own.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If DBQL USECOUNT logging is in effect, DBC.ColumnsV view gives an AccessCount (though you'd probably need to take a snapshot and compare to see if it is changing) and LastAccessTImestamp. But note that if someone does a `SELECT *` then all columns are "accessed" even if the data is not used, and that an UPDATE to the column is also considered and "access" though INSERT or DELETE of a row is not.

Comment: Hm, I had not considered that things like `SELECT *` and `UPDATE` would be counted as a column being accessed, but it makes sense. I ended up just having a DB admin run an ad hoc query for me, but given the things you pointed out I'm not sure the results are actually what I was after.